# Installing earlier version of R package not on CRAN

Tags: r

I am developing an R package that will not be hosted on GitHub or submitted to CRAN. I am using git for version control. I would like to give my users the ability to load older versions of the package. I've read [here](https://combine-australia.github.io/r-pkg-dev/versioning.html) about `usethis::use_version()` for versioning my package. This will track the versions using git, but I'm wondering if there's a straightforward way for my end users to load an older version without having to use git themselves. For packages hosted on CRAN, I know the [versions package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/versions/index.html) can be used to achieve this.

Right now my best solution is to create a copy of the R package in a new directory when starting work on a new version. Then the end users can load the version they want by choosing the appropriate directory. If there is a better solutions than this, I would be interested to hear it.

Comment: @MrFlick Thank you very much. `remotes::install_git()` looks like it might do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `remotes::install_git()` function has a `ref=` parameter when you type a commit or tag name. If you tag your releases, then you can install which ever version you want with the correct tag. Your users don't need to run git themselves, but they will need access to the git repo to pull the correct version.

If you want to host your own repository for your users, you can also look into something like [miniCRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/miniCRAN/vignettes/miniCRAN-introduction.html) or [drat](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/drat.html). Since those basically a CRAN-like repository for your packages, you can probably use existing tools like the versions package to interact with the repo (assuming you keep older versions around in the same way CRAN does).

Comment: Follow-up question: It looks like `remotes::install_git()` requires a url pointing to a private or public repository. Does that mean it will not work if the package is only stored locally and not hosted online?

Comment: Well, it depends on what you mean by "hosted locally." If it only on your machine and no where else, then yes. that won't work. The users need to have access to the repo. There are many ways to share a repo other than using github. You could clone the repo to whatever location you were going to put the folder containing older versions.

Comment: The repository can be put on a shared network drive where users could access it. But what would the url argument be in that case, just the path to where the repository is?

Comment: It would just be a `file://` path URL to the location.